# Unity UpdateExternalTexture from MovieTexture windows crash

Tags: c#, windows, graphics, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I'm trying to play a `MovieTexture` object with a `SpriteRenderer` object.
My code is working fine on OSX.

It **crashes** my windows 7 **exported game**, and play mode in **Unity editor** in windows 7.

I am sure the `currentTexture.UpdateExternalTexture()` call is making it crash, but I can't figure out why.

Can anybody explain why this is not working or how to debug it? The Unity log file didn't contain anything that seemed useful, just the message `Crashed.`

Here is what I am using

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FMAC_VideoPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

public string animationName = "escalator";

MovieTexture movieTexture;
Texture2D currentTexture;
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
Sprite sprite;

void Start () 
{
    movieTexture = Resources.Load (animationName) as MovieTexture;

    currentTexture = new Texture2D(movieTexture.width, movieTexture.height);
    currentTexture.UpdateExternalTexture(movieTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr());

    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
    sprite = Sprite.Create (currentTexture, new Rect(Vector2.zero, new Vector2(movieTexture.width, movieTexture.height)), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite;

    movieTexture.Play();
}
}
```

Ideas?

**Update**

I have `Debug.Log()` ed the native texture pointer which prints the pointer address (ex. 556409680 ), so it does not seem to be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

On Unity [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr.html) for `GetNativeTexturePtr()` I found this line:

> On platforms that do not support native code plugins, this function always returns NULL.

This may be the issue, passing `null` as a parameter will cause a crash. As for how to fix it, I would say test for the value of that to be `null` and run alternate code that is guaranteed to work.

Comment: That's a good guess, I just tried to check for null but it seems to have a valid value. I have updated the question with this.

Comment: I am not too good with low level programming but I believe pointers can point to null values. Try `.ToInt32()` to get the value of the pointer.

Comment: Good point again. Tried it and it prints the same value as before. So I'm thinking the toInt32() value is the one that is printed by default in the case of this type of object.

Comment: I don't really have any more ideas, have you tried the Unity stackexchange? They may be able to give some tips on the unity end of it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I wasn't aware there was a Unity specific stack exchange. I posted it unity answers and now on the Unity Stack Exchange.